# How do I backup files stored in Rackspace Cloud Files container to an Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, rackspace, synchronization, amazon-s3

I'm currently storing PDF reports in a Rackspace cloud files container. These files are generated from a web application. I'm keen to find a way to sync these files to an Amazon s3 container as a form of backup/redundancy.

So far I've only come across this PHP script which (with a few modifications to fix bugs) seems to work:

http://quicloud.com/blog/cross-provider-cloud-file-backups-rackspace-cloudfiles-amazon-s3.html

I'm wondering if there are any better ways to achieve this on Ubuntu (command line).

Comment: I think this opens some sort of a rift in the time-space continuum...

Answer (score 1):

Would be interested to hear the bug fixes in that script. Last we tested (when we wrote the blog), all worked well. If you can email me separately (rich at quicloud dot com), or call us via the #s on our contact page, I'd love to roll any fixes you found back into the source.

And to answer your question, we still don't see any easier/better way to do this (unfortunately). I've heard there are some desktop clients out there that can do this (like cyberduck on mac), but nothing that can run server-side aside from custom rolled.